# Hughes' Fibonacci stream

Tags: haskell, fibonacci, frp, arrows

I am trying to understand the "Streams as arrows" section in John Hughes' famous ["Generalising Arrows to Monads"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167642399000234). To be more precise, I am interested in writing down the Fibonacci stream.

I tweaked Hughes' definition a bit:

```
data StreamProcessor a b = Get (a -> StreamProcessor a b) | 
                           Put b (StreamProcessor a b) |
                           Halt
put = Put
get = Get
```

First of all, I treat stream processors as lists which may block (waiting for input). That is:

- `Put :: b -> StreamProcessor a b -> StreamProcessor a b` matches `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`;
- `Halt :: StreamProcessor a b` matches `[] :: [a]`;
- `Get :: (a -> StreamProcessor a b) -> StreamProcessor a b` helps us block the stream and wait for input.

Therefore, if we drop the `Get` we get a list-like structure. If we also drop `Halt` we get an infinite-list-like structure.

Here are two ways I would understand "a stream of Fibonaccis":

- a non-blocked infinite stream (infinite-list-like):

  ```
  zipNonBlockedStreamsWith :: (a -> b -> c) 
                              -> StreamProcessor () a 
                              -> StreamProcessor () b
                              -> StreamProcessor () c
  zipNonBlockedStreamsWith f (Put x sp) (Put y sp') 
   = Put (f x y) (zipNonBlockedStreamsWith f sp sp')
  zipNonBlockedStreamsWith f Halt       sp          = Halt  
  zipNonBlockedStreamsWith f sp         Halt        = Halt

  fibs :: StreamProcessor () Int
  fibs = 
   put 0 (put 1 $ zipNonBlockedStreamsWith (+) fibs (tailNonBlockedStream fibs))

  -- matches a well-known definition of an infinite Fibonacci list.
  fibsList :: [Int]
  fibsList = 0 : 1 : (zipWith (+) fibsList (tail fibsList))

  -- with the 'fibsList', we can use folds to do the same thing.
  putStream :: [b] -> StreamProcessor a b -> StreamProcessor a b
  putStream bs sp = foldr Put sp bs

  fibs' :: StreamProcessor () Int
  fibs' = putStream fibsList Halt
  ```
- A blocked stream waits for `n`, outputs the `n`th Fibonacci number and blocks again. Hughes' `Arrow` interface helps us express it in a quite concise way:

  ```
  instance Category StreamProcessor where
    ...

  instance Arrow StreamProcessor where
    arr f = Get $ \ a -> Put (f a) (arr f)
    ...

  fibsList :: [Int]
  fibsList = 0 : 1 : (zipWith (+) fibsList (tail fibsList))

  blockedFibs :: StreamProcessor Int Int
  blockedFibs = arr (fibsList !!)
  ```

Yet, in [the paper I linked](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167642399000234) John Hughes shows another solution, `Arrow`ing his way through:

```
instance Category StreamProcessor where
  id = Get (\ x -> Put x id)
  
  Put c bc . ab = Put c (bc . ab)
  Get bbc . Put b ab = (bbc b) . ab
  Get bbc . Get aab = Get $ \ a -> (Get bbc) . (aab a)
  Get bbc . Halt = Halt
  Halt . ab = Halt

bypass :: [b] -> [d] -> StreamProcessor b c -> StreamProcessor (b, d) (c, d)
bypass [] ds (Get f)          = Get $ \ ~(b, d) -> bypass [] (ds ++ [d]) (f b)
bypass (b : bs) [] (Get f)    = bypass bs [] (f b)
bypass [] (d : ds) (Put c sp) = Put (c, d) $ bypass [] ds sp
bypass bs [] (Put c sp) =      
  Get $ \ ~(b, d) -> Put (c, d) (bypass (bs ++ [b]) [] sp)
bypass bs ds Halt             = Halt

instance Arrow StreamProcessor where
  arr f = Get $ \ a -> Put (f a) (arr f)
  first = bypass [] []

liftArr2 :: Arrow k => (a -> b -> c) -> k r a -> k r b -> k r c
liftArr2 f a b = a &&& b >>^ uncurry f

fibsHughes = let 
              fibsHughes' = put 1 (liftArr2 (+) fibsHughes fibsHughes')
             in put 0 fibsHughes'
```

But it does not work the way I expect. The following function would help us take the values from the stream until it blocks or halts (using `Data.List.unfoldr`):

```
popToTheBlockOrHalt :: StreamProcessor a b -> [b]
popToTheBlockOrHalt = let
                         getOutput (Put x sp) = Just (x, sp)
                         getOutput getOrHalt  = Nothing
                      in unfoldr getOutput
```

So, here is what we get:

```
GHCi> popToTheBlockOrHalt fibsHughes
[0, 1]
GHCi> :t fibsHughes
fibsHughes :: StreamProcessor a Integer
```

If we check the patterns, we would see that it blocks (that is we stumble into `Get`).

I cannot tell whether it should be that way. If it is what we want, why? If not, what is the problem? I checked and rechecked the code I wrote and it pretty much matches the definitions in Hughes' article (well, I had to add `id` and patterns for `Halt` - I cannot see how they could have messed the process up).

---

**Edit:** As it is said in the comments, in the [later edition of the paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167642399000234) `bypass` was slightly changed (we use that one). It is able to accumulate both withheld `b`s and `d`s (that is has two queues), whereas the `bypass` from the [original paper](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Erjmh/Papers/arrows.pdf) accumulates just `d`s (that is one queue).

---

**Edit #2:** I just wanted to write down a function which would pop the Fibonacci numbers from the `fibsHughes`:

```
popToTheHaltThroughImproperBlocks :: StreamProcessor () b -> [b]
popToTheHaltThroughImproperBlocks = let
                                       getOutput (Put x sp) = Just (x, sp)
                                       getOutput (Get c)    = getOutput $ c ()
                                       getOutput Halt       = Nothing
                                    in unfoldr getOutput
```

And here we go:

```
GHCi> (take 10 . popToTheHaltThroughImproperBlocks) fibsHughes 
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]
```

Comment: Is this modified version of bypass in the linked paper? I think the problem is the definition of `(&&&)` but I'm still trying to pinpoint the core issue.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia it is in the paper’s other edition, posted in 2000. I will look for the link and add it to the post.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I changed the links. The link to the earlier edition is still there - in the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the paper. Where exactly the blame lies is largely a matter of subjective interpretation. I think it's an overlooked bug in the paper due to  the type `StreamProcessor` not being as intuitive as it may seem.

To first focus on the concrete example of the `fibsHughes` stream, it indeed contains `Get`, but they are constant functions. You must feed some arguments to access the rest of the stream. In a way, the "true" type of `fibsHughes` is `SP () b` whereas what you might intuitively want is `SP Void b` to encode the absence of `Get` (which doesn't quite work that way, and that's kinda the source of the problem), and "feeding" it input is how you get from one to the other:

```hs
type SP = StreamProcessor

feed :: SP () b -> SP Void b
feed p = produceForever () >>> p

produceForever :: b -> SP Void b
produceForever b = Put b (produceForever b)

fibsHughes :: SP Void b
fibsHughes = feed (... {- rest of the definition -})
```

---

Now to see how we got into this situation, we have to go back to the definition of `first`. My opinion is that it is a questionable operation on streams to define in the first place, because it has to introduce `Get` actions to be able to produce the second component of the pairs as output:

```hs
first ::: SP a b -> SP (a, c) (b, c)
```

The problematic part is the following branch in the definition of `bypass`, which introduces the `Get` to then be able to `Put`:

```hs
bypass bs [] (Put c sp) =      
  Get $ \ ~(b, d) -> Put (c, d) (bypass (bs ++ [b]) [] sp)
```

It is what you need to do if you want to write something of the expected type, but it is arguably not a natural thing to do.

Having defined `first` is what leads to defining and using the `(&&&)` operator, which has unintuitive semantics. To see why it's unintuitive, specialize `(&&&)` with `Void` as the stream input type:

```hs
(&&&) :: SP Void b -> SP Void c -> SP Void (b, c)
```

Anyone who looks at this would think that, of course, the result must be a producer, which never `Get`s anything, that would be absurd. Except that `(&&&)` does the absurd thing; thus specialized to `Void`, it is morally equivalent to the following (ignoring the existence of `undefined` which can technically be used to tell them apart in Haskell):

```hs
_ &&& _ = Get (absurd :: Void -> SP a c)
```

---

There is a more natural definition of `(&&&)` by recursion on streams which avoids that issue: if the two arguments never do any `Get`, then the result never does any `Get` either.

As far as I can tell, this "better" `(&&&)` cannot be defined using `first`, `(>>>)` and `arr`.

However, it comes at cost: it is not intuitive from the point of view of a graphical interpretation of arrows, because it breaks this equation (which can be drawn graphically as "sliding" `f` out of `&&&`):

```hs
f &&& g   =   (id &&& g) >>> first f
```

Whichever definition of `(&&&)` you choose, it is going to confuse someone.

---

IMO it comes down to the type `StreamProcessor` not being able to rule out the use of `Get`. Even if the input type is `Void`, a stream can still do a vacuous `Get`.

A better type of stream processor without such definitional issues is the one from the [pipes library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes) (called [`Proxy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.14/docs/Pipes-Internal.html#t:Proxy)). In particular, it differs from `SP` because it can forbid the use of `Get`, and that provides a faithful encoding of true "producers" such as the Fibonacci stream.

Comment: >it indeed contains Get, but they are constant functions.< Weirdly enough, when I pattern-matched `Get f` and tried applying `f` to different arguments, it just hanged. It really does seem like some kind of a bottom to me. Did you have `f` produce legitimate output working with `bypass` (with two queues) or `bypass'` (with one queue)?

Comment: Yes I took the code from your post and just tweaked how it gets processed, and got  the Fibonacci numbers out of that stream: https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/b864da64ad56f17314f8924232c8c17b

Comment: You are right, sorry. I also stumble into this `Get`-`Put` iteration: no bottoms :).

Comment: Why would you want `feed :: SP () x -> SP Void x`? The natural type for a stream that takes no input is indeed just `SP () x`. You simply want to "normalize" `SP () x` that contain `Get`s to `SP () x`s that contain no `Get`s (i.e. `[x]`).

Comment: @HTNW, as the `Proxy` type suggests, the idea one might intuitively try to express as `SP Void x` that the stream cannot await) needs to be expressed a different way. In the case of `Proxy` that's managed by replacing the bland "await" by a richer "request".

Answer (score 1):

I think one confusion you may have is that, while you can find a correlation between stream processors and lists that may block, they are not exactly the same.  Morally, a `StreamProcessor a b` consumes a stream of `a` and produces a stream of `b`.  (One odd thing about Hughes' paper is that he doesn't explicitly define what a stream is.)  What this boils down to is that your `popToTheBlockOrHalt` function never actually provides an input stream, but it still expects the given stream processor to produce an output stream.

Another thing to keep in mind is that in Hughes' paper, there is no `Halt` — stream processors are infinite and work on infinite streams.  So, for a so-called "producer" like `fibsHughes` (that is, a stream processor whose input stream is arbitrary), there really is no "blocking" going on even if there are `Get`s hidden internally because there is always more input from the input stream — it's infinite!

So, what you need to work with these stream processors is a way to *run* them, or to turn something of the form `StreamProcessor a b` into a function from a stream of `a` to a stream of `b`.  Because your version allows the streams to be finite, it makes sense to use regular old lists as your "stream" type.  Thus, you want a function with a type like:

```hs
runStreamProcessor :: StreamProcessor a b -> [a] -> [b]
```

There is a natural definition for this:

```hs
runStreamProcessor Halt _ = []
runStreamProcessor (Put x s) xs = x : runStreamProcessor s xs
runStreamProcessor _ [] = []
runStreamProcessor (Get f) (x:xs) = runStreamProcessor (f x) xs
```

Now, you can consider the type of `runStreamProcessor fibsHughes :: [a] -> [Integer]` and realize that, naturally, you must supply, e.g., `repeat ()` in order to guarantee an infinite output stream.  This works:

```
> take 10 $ runStreamProcessor fibsHughes (repeat ())
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't think you got the question right. The function which would *run* the `fibsHughes` stream is written down in **Edit #2** - `popToTheHaltThroughImproperBlocks` (although I made it the other way - thank you for showing the 2<sup>nd</sup> one). The question is why those blocks are there in the 1<sup>st</sup> place. You are right about calling `fibsHughes` a *producer*, yet I see no reason to allow (or even put) `Get`s into producers.

Comment: My point is that the internals are irrelevant -- as I said, given the domain of infinite streams, they're not blocks at all.  It's like having "no-ops" in code -- sure, they're not necessary, but they're also indistinguishable _by any appropriate view_ to their absence.